# Getting element in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im wondering if there's a way to get the id attribute i have in each row of my table using the onclick event i have on each "a" element. I have tried something like this but it always get the first one:

```
   <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
  <thead> 
<tr> 
<th class="header headerSortDown">Last Name</th> 
<th class="header">First Name</th> 
<th class="header headerSortUp">Email</th> 
<th class="header">Due</th> 
<th class="header">Web Site</th>
<th class="header">Del</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr class="tableContent" id="1"> 
<td>Smith</td> 
<td>John</td> 
<td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
<td>$50.00</td> 
<td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>  
<td><a onclick="getid();">Del</a></td>
 </tr> 
 <tr class="tableContent" id="2"> 
<td>Bach</td> 
<td>Frank</td> 
<td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
<td>$50.00</td> 
<td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
<td><a onclick="getid();">Del</a></td>
 </tr> 
 <tr class="tableContent" id="3"> 
<td>Doe</td> 
<td>Jason</td> 
<td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
<td>$100.00</td> 
<td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
<td><a onclick="getid();">Del</a></td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 


function getid(){

var id = $("a").closest(".tableContent").attr("id");
alert(id);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the HTML to:

```
<td><a onclick="getid(this);">Del</a></td>
```

And the JS to:

```
function getid(el) {
    var id = $(el).closest(".tableContent").attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. i get Unexpected token this in function getid(this){}

Comment: @user1763639: In the `getid()` function definition, change both occurrences of `this` to `elem` or something similar. `function getid(elem) { var id = $(elem).closest(...`

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing a reference of the item that was clicked. I would avoid inline event handlers though (especially when using jQuery), and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tableContent a').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.tableContent').attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Just for the sake of completeness, here's how you could do it with the inline event handler:

`<a onclick="getid(this);">Del</a>`

```
function getid(obj){
    var id = $(obj).closest(".tableContent").attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
```